# Put BMP image into 2D array and edit RGB values in C

Tags: c, arrays, rgb, bmp

Okay guys, I am new to C and I am a trying to construct a 2D array that will hold a BMP image and be able to edit the RGB values. I haven't been able to find anything online about how to access the RGB values or how to put this image in the 2D array and I am really stuck as to where to start. HELP!!!!

Comment: .. and that was second one on the list from Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the reference [Writing BMP image in pure c/c++ without other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries) of Ed Heal. Things to note:

- Define the structures. Don't use arrays of unsigned chars to make the headers as in the referenced post.
- Both in reading and writing, take care to fill the scanlines. They must be a multiple of four, so the last bytes may not be pixels and contain garbage.

See also my earlier post [What is wrong with this code for writing grey-scale bmp from an image RGB bmp pure C - Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844871/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-for-writing-grey-scale-bmp-from-an-image-rgb-bmp-pu/31850208#31850208) which contains the headers and can serve as a partial example.

Comment: Thanks! I think part of my issue is mainly knowing what to look for. My instructor is extremely non-specific and gave us no examples. We just learned how to use 2D arrays in C and she the gave us this homework that seemed like an extreme logical jump to apply it to images, she didn't even teach us about importing images yet!