# Convert image to grayscale without using opencv

Tags: c

I want to change my color image file to grayscale image file.

I can't use OPENCV and other library.

My code algorithm is like this.

```
T[3] = {0.299, 0.589, 0.114}

N = size of vertical
M = size of horizontal

for j = 1 ~ N

{
  for i = 1 ~ M
  Writebuf[i][j] = Readbuf[0][i+M][i] * T[0] + Readbuf[1][i+M][i] * T[1] + Readbuf[2][i+M][i] * T[2]
}
```

This is my code following algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main() {
    FILE* fp;

    double T[3] = { 0.299, 0.587, 0.114 };

    int N = 374;
    int M = 374;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    unsigned char Readbuf[374][374];
    unsigned char Writebuf[374][374];

    fp = fopen("lena_color.bmp", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("FIle Read Error");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        fread(Readbuf[i], 1, N, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            
            Writebuf[j][i] = Readbuf[0][j + M][i] * T[0] + Readbuf[1][j + M][i] * T[1] + Readbuf[2][j + M][i] * T[2];
        }
    }
    fp = fopen("111.bmp", "wb");
    for (i = 0; i < 374; i++);
        fwrite(Writebuf[i], 1, 374, fp);
    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't save image

Please help me.

Comment: OT: you check if `(fp == NULL)` and the you print an error message, but what happens then?

Comment: Also you don't check if `fp = fopen("111.bmp", "wb")` fails at all.

Comment: In your code, you declare `Readbuf` as a **two**-dimensional array but then access it as a **three**-dimensional array. Have I missed something?

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem? Does your code run but not behave as you expect or does your code not compile with an error message? I think latter is the case here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844871/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-for-writing-grey-scale-bmp-from-an-image-rgb-bmp-pu/31850208#31850208